# How to exclude HA backup pod from node group selector in kubernates?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I want to create nodegroup selector which contain only primary pod and exclude backup pod in kubernates. How to achieve that using helm chart ?

```
appVersion: version1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata: 
  name: statefulname
  label: 
    ....
    ....
    ....
spec:
  replica: 2

  .....
 container:
   .....
   ....
   nodeselecor:
    {{$nodegroup}}
```

here result is

```
 NAME                    READY   STATUS    STARTS   AGE
pod/zookeeper-np-0       1/1     Running   0        203s
pod/zookeeper-np-1       1/1     Running   0        137s
```

here replica create 2 instance of pod with suffix -0 and -1 and both have same node selector but i want to that for
`pod/zookeeper-np-0`  for this node selector is node group ng1
`pod/zookeeper-np-1`  for this node selector is node group ng2

i tried with iterate also not getting error

```
Caused By: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Identified another participant with the same name for Space: newspace_container_newspace
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not shared the K8s version details however you can look for the using the **Node affinity** with **statefulset** or else **topologySpreadConstraints**

```
topologySpreadConstraints:
    - maxSkew: <integer>
      topologyKey: <string>
      whenUnsatisfiable: <string>
      labelSelector: <object>
```

Read more at : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-topology-spread-constraints/

using the **topologySpreadConstraints** you can spread the PODs across the nodes.

**Node Affinity**

```
nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: kubernetes.io/e2e-az-name
            operator: In
            values:
            - e2e-az1
            - e2e-az2
```

Read more : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/

You can also use the node affinity to do the same scheduling the PODs on different nodes.

Comment: Is it work for assign different node group per pod?

Comment: you labels and key as per need and it will work

Answer (score 0):

> i want to that for pod/zookeeper-np-0  for this node selector is node
> group ng1 pod/zookeeper-np-1  for this node selector is node group ng2

Per StatefulSet you can only have one `nodeSelector` which apply to all pods under this StatefulSet control. If you need to place pod in specific node group, you need to run them in different StatefulSet with its own `nodeSelector`.